# WPF Successive TranslateTransform start position

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have an application with three navigable steps, lets say firstPage, secondPage and thirdPage.

I created a control for this navigation, with three buttons and a border that should always be under the active step’s button. To achieve that, I use an animation on the border, which moves from the last active step to the new one.

Here is the XAML that animates the border:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActivePage}" Value="FirstPage">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FirstPageStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ActivePageIndicator"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                     To="-185" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SecondPageStoryboard" />
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ThirdPageStoryboard" />
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActivePage}" Value="SecondPage">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SecondPageStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ActivePageIndicator"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                     To="0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FirstPageStoryboard" />
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ThirdPageStoryboard" />
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActivePage}" Value="ThirdPage">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ThirdPageStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ActivePageIndicator"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                     To="185" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FirstPageStoryboard" />
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SecondPageStoryboard" />
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Everything works fine, exept the transition from ThirdPage to SecondPage: the border directly sets its position to 0, with no animation.

If I replace 0 with 10 in the SecondPage storyboard, the border first resets its position to 0, and then slides to 10.

If I remove the StopStoryboard instructions, the border always stays to the step whose storyboard is defined last (if I navigate to SecondPage, and then back to FirstPage, the border stays on SecondPage, if I navigate to ThirdPage and then back to First or SecondPage, the border stays on ThirdPage).

I’ve tried moving the stopstoryboard to ExitAction or using FillBehavior= Stop with no success.

I know I could get it working using code behind and storyboard.completed, but is there a way to get it working with only XAML?